# iPhone/iPad screen balcks out when opening Xamarin iOS App

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms app. Its working fine with Android and Windows but when I am Debugging it in the iPhone/iPad then I am getting issue.

During debug it works fine but when I disconnect the device from the MacBook and then try to open the installed app then it doesnt open and after some time screen of the iPhone/iPad blacks out. I need to press Power button and Volume down button to make screen live.

What could be the issue?

Comment: There is virtually no way to determine what is happening without any code or logs. Please check out the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page on how to formulate a good question. That being said; go into Xcode and the devices screen, there try to access the logs of the device to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Issue is coming when I disconnect the phone from Mac and try to open the app in the phone.   When phone is connected to Mac then it works fine. I thought someone might faced this issue and have some solution that's why I asked it here